# How to send new visitor to a splash page for only one time in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, redirect

I have a PHP script that will be the main web platform and would like our NEW visitors that visit our domain to be sent to an (introduction type) Wordpress splash page, and we want this to happen only one time per user. Any returning users coming back to our website will see the main web platform and not be directed to the WP splash page
(assumingly until their cookies are cleared).

Comment: You have 2 systems: WordPress and custom platform - right? So in order to achieve this, you'll now need a 3rd system - the one, that does the redirect. Setting a cookie on the WP site and checking for that within the redirect system should be possible. Have you researched this further or tried anything yet?

Comment: No, I do not have that much coding experience. Can you help me?